# Displaying and changing text by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So what I'm trying to do is have a big empty box that displays a question when the user types in a specific string.  Then when the user answers the question, the previous text changes into the next question.  I honestly have no idea on where to even start.  I know this is going to be tricky, and I apologize in advanced for not having code.  Thanks a bunch for your help though.

Comment: it is very long title man

Comment: Are you trying to make a form where a user fills out? As in... "What colour is your hair today?" user answers "hello pineapple" and moves on to the next question, or does this require some validation?

In fact, I don't even think anyone can really help you since you don't even know what you are looking for exactly. At times like these, it might be best to just HIRE someone.

Comment: So this "big empty box" isn't going to be empty since you want to display a question(text) inside.... as for the previous text changing into the next question, I believe we call that dynamic data. The next question/data will overwrite the existing question/data but won't you need to check the answer is correct before moving to the next question? If not then how do you plan on keeping track of the answers given and correct/incorrect answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example built with jQuery. You can add whatever questions you want to the `questions` object and it will ask them. This assumes there is only one answer for each question.

```js
//define array of questions
var questions = [{
  "q": "What is 1 + 1",
  "a": "2"
}, {
  "q": "What is 3 + 1",
  "a": "4"
}];


//question function
askQuestion = function(index) {
  //set question text
  $('#question').text(questions[index].q);
  
  //set answer event listener
  $('#quiz').off().submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var answer = $('#answer').val();

    //check if answer is incorrect
    if (answer !== questions[index].a) {
      alert('try again!');
    } else {
      //rest form
      $('#answer').val('');
      //call next question if
      //current is not last
      if (questions.length > index + 1) {
        askQuestion(index + 1);
      } else{
        $('#quiz').hide();
        $('#finished').show();
      }
    }
  });
}

//start quiz
askQuestion(0);
```

```css
//hide finished message
#finished{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- quiz -->
<form id='quiz'>
  <h1 id='question'><h1>
  <input id='answer' type='text'>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<!-- text to be displayed after quiz -->
<h1 id='finished'>Great Job!<h1>
```

Comment: I think it would be a good idea for you to put comments in your code or explain the source code. Allowing people to copy/paste source code without understanding it removes the point of helping someone. Understanding the answer is more important than getting the answer.

Comment: Try it now? I know it works, I also understand it line for line but with such a broad question being asked i'm just recommending you to explain the answer since Dani Valentine hasn't given any source code to work with you have to assume they don't/won't know your method since they haven't made/shown any attempt of doing this on their own. *(Not picking but I have noticed you forgot to change the h1 tag style, display none to block when the answers are completed)*